# De onde vem a expressão "Roupa encardida" e qual o seu verdadeiro significado?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu

De onde vem a expressão 
"Roupa encardida"

Comment: Para os curiosos que não conhecem esta expressão, pode [edit]ar a sua pergunta para explicar o significado, por favor?

Comment: A edição parece que não foi bem recebida. Direito a  -

Comment: Não fui eu que votei, mas também acho a pergunta um pouco estranha. Há alguma dúvida acerca do significado? *Roupa encardida* não é simplesmente ’roupa que está encardida’? Se é, então tens a origem de *roupa* e a origem de *encardida*. E *roupa encardida* é simplesmente a combinação normal das duas palavras, tal como em *roupa bonita* ou *pele encardida*. Seria diferente, por exemplo, em *roupa velha* no sentido ’comida’, que é diferente de ’roupa que está velha’, e que tem uma origem própria posterior às origens de *roupa* e *velha* e independente delas.  >>

Comment: >> Portanto tu estás especialmente interessado no primeiro uso de *roupa encardida*? Ou estás interessado é no *encardido*? Pode-se ter falado em *mãos encardidas* ou *parede encardida* antes de em roupa encardida. Acho que isto é que é importante clarificar.

Comment: Quer-me parecer até que o @DanGetz pensou que *roupa encardida* tivesse um significado especial (como *roupa velha* ’comida’), diferente da combinação dos significados de *roupa* e *encardida* (se tem, eu desconheço). Nesses casos é que falamos em "expressão"; caso contrário, é só uma combinação normal de palavras.

Comment: Roupa velha é igual a roupa encardida?

Comment: *Roupa velha* é um contra-exemplo. *Roupa velha* é o nome de uma comida que se prepara com restos. Portanto poderíamos querer saber quando é que esse nome apareceu, onde, quem é que inventou (não é certo é que se conseguisse responder a essas perguntas). Pelo contrário, *roupa encardida* é simplesmente roupa que está encardida. A origem de *roupa encardida* é do mesmo tipo que a origem de *roupa vistosa* ou *roupa garrida* ou *maçã madura* ou *gato malhado*; isto são apenas combinações de duas palavras, ao contrário de *roupa velha* que é diferente de *roupa que está velha*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A palavra *encardido* decerto vem do verbo *encardir*, mas *encardir* tem origem duvidosa, alguns dicionários dizem uma coisa, outros dizem outra. Eis um resuminho:

a palavra *encardir* tem origem duvidosa, tida como derivada de *cárdeo* (ou *cardo* ou *carda*) no sentido de 'arroxeado' ou de cardo; notar, contudo, que *encardir* é de 1858 e *cardido*, anterior (século XIV), assim autoriza a hipótese de *encardir* ser derivado de en- + cardido.

Fontes: [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/encardir), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/encardir) e [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#2).

Answer (score 1):

Palavra de origem brasileira ( Encardido ) - se encardiu que ficou amarelado ou acizentada  pelo tempo ou lavagens mal feitas, sujo ou imundo.

Está roupa está encardida.

Está roupa está suja, mal lavada.

Comment: Do Brasil? Consegue alguma referência?

Answer (score 1):

Ela vem do Latim CARDO, o nome de um planta cuja cor é muito pouco viva, fazendo pensar num pano mal lavado.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas, geralmente com referências. Isso é especialmente importante nesse caso, em que, conforme [a resposta do Schilive](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8833/2764) esclarece, a etimologia de "encardido" na verdade é desconhecida, ou ao menos duvidosa.